# Finding limit using Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, riemann-integration

I am doing a self study of real analysis and this comes up and I can't find any problems like it:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sin\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\sec^2\biggl(\frac{1}{3n}\biggr)+\sec^2\biggl(\frac{4}{3n}\biggr)+\cdots +\sec^2\biggl(\frac{3n-5}{3n}\biggr)+\sec^2\biggl(\frac{3n-2}{3n}\biggr)\Biggr)$$

As much as I have been able to do is possibly change it to

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sin\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sec^2\biggl(\frac{3k-2}{3n}\biggr)$$

Any help is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

$$\sin(1/n) \sum_{k=1}^n \sec^2 \left ( \frac{3k-2}{3n} \right ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sec^2 \left ( \frac{3k-2}{3n} \right ) + \left ( \sin(1/n) - \frac{1}{n} \right ) \sum_{k=1}^n \sec^2 \left ( \frac{3k-2}{3n} \right ).$$

That first term is an actual Riemann sum; you are evaluating $\sec^2$ at certain points inside the partition $0,1/n,\dots,1$. So the limit of that is $\int_0^1 \sec^2(x) dx$, which you can calculate.

In the second term, you have that all the terms in the sum are less than $\sec^2(1)$, so the whole sum is less than $n \sec^2(1)$. So that whole term is less than $\sec^2(1)(1-n\sin(1/n))$ in magnitude. That goes to zero because $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$.

Comment: I unfortunately know nothing about correction terms.  I haven't had the conventional math education so I am usually playing catch up.  So, I understand why $\frac{1}{n}$ would make everything work well.  But, the $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ part is a definite curveball.  Where does one normally learn about correction terms?

Comment: @JaLo Oh, let me rephrase for your background.

Comment: That is beautiful!  Thank you!